# How to unlock madhouse difficulty?

Tags: resident-evil-7

There are 3 difficult levels available for Resident Evil 7: Easy, Normal, and Madhouse.

Unless you bought the specific pre-order that unlocks Madhouse difficulty fromt he start then this mode is locked by default.

Usually Resident Evil games require you to complete the game on a lower difficult first, but what I would like to know is: do you have to complete it on Normal to unlock it, or will Easy suffice?

Or maybe I am wrong with my assumption that it unlocks on game completion...

How can I unlock Madhouse difficulty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this article](http://twinfinite.net/2017/01/resident-evil-7-how-unlock-madhouse-difficulty-whats-different/) you must first beat the game on any difficulty:

> There are two ways to unlock this mode. The first is to have pre-ordered the game which grants a code that unlocks this mode from the very beginning. **The second is to beat the game once on any difficulty mode.**

[This article](http://twinfinite.net/2017/01/resident-evil-7-all-madhouse-difficulty-differences/) (though from the same website) states the same thing.

> ...or by beating the game once on any difficulty.

I believe the previous entry in the series was also the same, and likely were many of the other Resident Evils.